# Can I use .htaccess to convert a url slug to a POST request?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use .htaccess to take a URL like this:

mydomain.com/some-url-slug

and instead redirects the user to mydomain.com, but with a POST request that includes "some-url-slug".

Is this possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

NO it's not possible - `mod_rewrite` rules cannot alter or rewrite POST data.

Obviously there are some security constraints in doing so, hence mod_rewrite developers didn't allow that.