# Can I use .HTACESS to submit an Html form?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to find a way to redirect 404 and 503 errors (and similar types) to a page via .HTACCESS, but with some added values.

Example - if a person lands on a 404 error page, the link would normally look like:
https://www.yourdomain.com/pages/404

How would you get it like:

https://www.yourdomain.com/pages/404?submit=error&msg=3

(in POST or alternatively GET data)

This question translates part of what I'm looking for, but not quite (as the answer is clearly 'No'):
[Can I use .htaccess to convert a url slug to a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345102/can-i-use-htaccess-to-convert-a-url-slug-to-a-post-request)

Can this be done, and are there any security implications if it was done?

This is in error_page.php:

```
    if ((isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit'] == 'error') || (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'error')) {

    $success_message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['msg']);

    switch ($success_message) {
        case '2':
            echo "<h2>Page under Maintenance</h2>";
            echo "<p>This page is currently undergoing some critical maintenance. You can try again in a couple hours.</p> For any help or enquiries send us a message on ".$support_email."";
            break;
        case '3':
            echo "<h2>404 Page Not Found</h2>";
            echo "<p>It seems the page you're looking for doesn't exist...</p>";
            mail($errors_email, 'Alert: 404 Not Found', 'A user (ref '.$user_ref.' with IP address '.$ip_address.') landed on this page ('.$current_url.') from '.$previous_url.' with a 404 error. Care to see what went wrong?');
            break;  
        default:
            mail($errors_email, 'User Landed on an Unknown Error Page', 'A user ('.$user_ref.') landed on the success_template.php page and something went wrong. This is just an alert to test all of the forms pointing to this page to see if they are valid.');
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mplungjan I'll check, thanks. (I realize if you're skilled in something you'll be able to find anything on Google. As a beginner having no idea if this was even possible, I wouldn't have found it with even a thousand google searches.)

Comment: I am not sure it IS possible, I just wanted to give you a relevant search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your own php scripts to handle the redirections:
eg: `handle_redir.php` or `404.php` etc.

in your .htacces you can redir 404 503 errors ... etc. to your `handle_redir.php`

`ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/handle_redir.php?%{REQUEST_URI}`

or

`ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/handle_redir.php?submit=error&msg=3`

Then in your script `handle_redir.php` you can use

`if(isset($_GET["submit"]) && $_GET["submit"] == "error") //do something`

Comment: Gee this was exactly what I was looking for. Is the difference between your two examples ({REQUEST_URI}) for a POST and GET form?

Comment: Yes. htaccess doesn't do anything with post data. It works on urls.

Comment: With `{%REQUEST_URI}` you receive the original request from client: eg: if the user post or get `http://your_domain.com/path1/path2?variable1=value1&variable2=value2` then in `{%REQUEST_URI}` you receive `/path1/path2?variable1=value1&variable2=value2`

Comment: So on `POST` or `GET` you receive the same `REQUEST_URI` ... If you want to know if the request is `POST` or `GET` you can use in php: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` ... also you can use `$_REQUEST['your_variable_name']` etc does no matter if is `POST` or `GET`

Comment: @MTK I see! ... Just tested this out, and I'm getting the proper response (the url is being received) however it's just echoing it out into the document body. I'm trying to redirect users who land on a 404 error page to this: ```error_page.php/?submit=error&msg=3``` , and there's a code to check the errors on that page. But nothing happens: If I go to an unknown location, it simply stays on the same page with no 404 error and the url ```"error_page?submit=error&msg=3"```. What exactly is happening?

Comment: So post your `error_page.php` code (editing your original question) and we will see what is the problem

Comment: First I think you have that in your .htacess: `ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/error_page.php?submit=error&msg=3`  ...   In this case you think you are in the default case on `switch ($success_message)` ... Then you can add one `echo "your message to client"` before `mail()`

Comment: also check `if(isset($_POST["msg"])){//run your mysql query}else{echo "required data missing" or $_POST["msg"] = 3 ... for your case 3: on switch}`

Comment: Guess what... since I'm on localhost, the {HTTP_HOST} was not giving the actual directory. I changed it to ```{HTTP_HOST}/websiteFolder/error_page.php?submit=error&msg=3``` and it started working as expected! Gee, thanks for staying with me, your tips helped tons :-)

Comment: One more tip: If this is to practice this well but in the real world (production site) remember: NEVER TRUST ON DATA COMING FROM CLIENT ... So before your SQL query check each $ _POST .. $ _GET if contain expected characters. .. take a look to: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
also search information about PDO and prepared statemens

Comment: Yep, this is just for testing purposes. Will go all out on the SQL injection protection once it goes live :-)